# CSS3 dropdown menu doesn't work in IE when included

Tags: php, html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm struggling with an issue for a while now, and I finally managed to figure out what caused it.

I've been trying to create a pretty dropdown menu in CSS3. I've tried several things, but for some reason I never got it working in Internet Explorer. I follow tutorials, I basically copy and pasted dropdown menu's from the internet, without any results.

A few minutes ago (from this post) I didn't see a single error in my script. I loaded my dropdown menu (placed in navigation.html) on it's own and the dropdown menu worked (in any browser). However, it didn't on my home page (index.php). It seems like including the page (navigation.html) causes the problem (just for Internet Explorer). So my question is: What is causing this? And is there any other way to include my Dropdown menu?

Here is the code of my navigation.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link href="includes/navigation.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="navigation">
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li class='active'><a href='#'><span>Home</span></a></li>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Projects</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='#'><span>Windows Desktop</span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>About</span></a></li>
   <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am including the **navigation.html** in the file named "**header.php**". **Header.php** is being included in **index.php**

***Index.php:***

```
<?php
        include("includes/credits.html");
        include("includes/header.php");
        include("includes/border.php");
    ?>
```

***Header.php:***

```
<div class="header" id="one">
<?php
    include("includes/navigation.html");
?></div>
```

Thanks in advance

***Edit: SOLVED***
I solved it by adding this meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

I just read at an article that this could cause problems for Internet Explorer, if you forgot to 'define' it.

Sorry for wasting your time!

Comment: I assume people know CSS3 doesn't work for IE8 and below (except for a couple of exceptions)

Comment: Yeah, IE8 is only CSS2.1 compliant ... but still IE9 and IE10 have important differences.

Comment: Not knowing what you have in the other files you are including it's hard to say, but it could be to do with a space ending up being the first element in the html code, which will chuck IE into 'quirks' mode. Other than that, another classic IE issue is that IE earlier versions don't support the :HOVER css pseudo selector on anything other than <A> tags.

Comment: - opalenzuela Alright. I will avoid that in the future.
@DarrenCrabb The dropdown menu works fine when I'm just loading the .html file (running "navigation.html" only. I've heard of that space problem before, but I forgot about it. How can I figure out if I've got this problem?

Comment: Edit: SOLVED I solved it by adding this meta tag:

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
I just read at an article that this could cause problems for Internet Explorer, if you forgot to 'define' it.

Sorry for wasting your time!

Comment: Glad you solved it ... with regards the space issue if your resulting code (and I was thinking something maybe contained in credits.html) has any whitespace before the first bit of code it will trigger the 'quirks' mode. You can simply look at the final page source to see if there's any space there.

Answer (score 0):

I could imagine older IEs having issues with CSS3, so could i'd recommend using jquery instead.

**HTML**

```
<ul id="navigation">
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Dropdown</a>
        <ul class="sub_navigation">
            <li><a href="#">Sub Navigation 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Navigation 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Navigation 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Dropdown 2</a>
        <ul class="sub_navigation">
            <li><a href="#">Sub Navigation 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Navigation 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Navigation 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('.dropdown').hover(function() {
            $(this).find('.sub_navigation').stop(true, true).fadeToggle(600); 
    });
```

**CSS**

```
   ul {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        list-style-type:none;
        min-width:200px;
    }

    ul#navigation {
        float:left;
    }

    ul#navigation li {
        float:left;
        border:1px black solid;
        min-width:200px;
    }

    ul.sub_navigation {
        position:absolute;
        display:none;
    }

    ul.sub_navigation li {
        clear:both;
    }

    a,
    a:active,
    a:visited {
        display:block;
        padding:10px;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v5CsV/